# Product of Jacobi theta functions

Tags: statistics, fourier-series, theta-functions

I need to calculate the following quantity:
$$
\zeta(x;\mu_1,\mu_2,\tau) = _3({x-\mu_1},) \cdot _3({x-\mu_2},)
$$
$_3(,)$ being the Jacobi theta function defined as:
$$
_3(,)=∑_{=−∞}^∞^{in^2+in2\pi}
$$
Note that $\tau$ is the same for both the thetas and is a purely imaginary quantity in the form $\tau = it, \ t \in \mathbb{R}^+$.
Under this conditions, $\zeta$ is the product of two Wrapped Normal (WN) distributions of the same variable having the same variance.

Is there a closed form for my expression above?